# finding the bit-width of an int in c; best-cross platform method

Tags: c, size, int, width, bit

I need to know the width(size) of a native int in the system which my code is being run, in bits.

I can get the width in chars using "sizeof", however, it is my understanding that no-where in the C spec does a char have a specific number of bits assigned to it.

So what is the best cross platform method for finding the bit width of an int?

Comment: "*... need to know the width(size) of ... in bits.*" should then the title better be: "*finding the **bit**-width of ...*"?

Comment: yes, my apologies - edited

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`CHAR_BIT` (from `<limits.h>`) is the number of bits in a `char`, so

```
sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT
```

is what you are looking for.

`CHAR_BIT` is specified in "5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types "
of the C99 standard.

*Added:* It might be interesting that the Open Group specification

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7999959899/basedefs/limits.h.html

states:

> The values for the limits {CHAR_BIT}, {SCHAR_MAX}, and {UCHAR_MAX} are
>   now required to be 8, +127, and 255, respectively.

Comment: If it were a Posix compliant system, you could just use `WORD_BIT`, fwiw. Otherwise, there is no guarantee that there are no padding bits in an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Open up `limits.h` and you should see all the info you need about sizes on your particular platform's integer limits.

This is how you determine how many bits in an `int`:

```
#include <limits.h>
printf("Number of bits in an int: %zu\n", sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT);
```

Open up `float.h` if you're interested in your particular platform's `float` and `double` limits.

Answer (score 0):

I would be very amazed if anything didn't use 8 bits per character.  You could fill a char with more then it should hold like 0xFFFF and see what it's value is.

Comment: Don't be too amazed! Larger than 8-bit characters is actually quite common.